Pageable spring-data-jpa how much data it takes from db?
I have table with 1000 rows.
I want to:

Select 50 rows with even id of table Tab and lock them for update

Update field checked and save it into Db.
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tab")
public class Tab {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer id;
 private Integer uuid;
 private Boolean checked;

 public void setId(Integer id) {
     this.id = id;
 }

 public void setUuid(Integer uuid) {
     this.uuid = uuid;
 }

 public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
     this.checked = checked;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "Tab{" +
             "id=" + id +
             ", uuid=" + uuid +
             '}';
 }



And JpaRepo:
public interface TabRepository extends JpaRepository<Tab, Integer> {


    @Query(value = "select t from Tab t where MOD(id, 2) = 0")
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @QueryHints({
            @QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value =  LockOptions.SKIP_LOCKED + "") // LockOptions.SKIP_LOCKED == -2
    })
    Page<Tab> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Override
    <S extends Tab> S save(S entity);
}

After getting data from postgre, i see in Log:

Extracted JDBC value [0] - [500]

Does it mean that per 1 transaction i got 500 rows and Pageable actually did not used in this case?
    @Transactional
    public Page<Tab> process() {
        int pageSize = 50;
        int page = 0;
        Page<Tab> resultPage;
        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("id"));
        resultPage = tabRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
    return resultPage
}
           
       


Which Spring Boot version are you using? Instead of javax.persistence.lock.timeout I would suggest to use AvailableSettings.JAKARTA_JPA_LOCK_TIMEOUT that way you will at least have the proper tag (I assume Spring Boot 3 which uses JakartaEE not JavaEE).

spring boot 3.2.5
